# http://dbpedia.org/sparql endpoint not reliable?

Tags: sparql

Sometimes a query works sometimes it doesn't. I get sometimes "Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out" (no timeout is set or a big timeout is set - so this is not the problem there is another problem behind that i am not aware of) or simply a browser HTTP 500 error page.
Sometimes it works from a new browser window in IE sometimes it doesn't work from FF.
What is going on with dbpedia sparql endpoint? Is there some caching or something that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DBPedia query service is kindly provided for free, and does tend to get (ab)used by many users. If you need something that you can rely on I'd suggest setting up your own instance (IIRC there are EC2 instances for that purpose).

It's a shame that the error messages tend to be so random.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But being limited to a normal PHP hosting account makes me unable to install the DB Pedia software. So i am going to not implement the DB Pedia sparql functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Due to Large set of data DBpedia is working very harse.It won't produce proper result.If you need better result try to setup ARQ for Sparql query on your localmachine.It will give better outcome.